# Trouble understanding MKMapPoint(s)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

Can anyone point me in the right direction when it comes to understanding `MKMapPoint`?

I understand that it has to do with laying suface of the globe on a 2D surface. But I don't understand how each "point" is measured?

Can anyone give me an example in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing much to it.. just a structure to display point on a 2D map... here is what the documentation says..

> MKMapPoint A point on a two-dimensional map projection.
>
> typedef struct {
>       double x;
>       double y; }  MKMapPoint;
>
> Fields x The location of the point along the x-axis of the
>   map. y The location of the point along the y-axis of
>   the map. Discussion If you project the curved surface of the globe
>   onto a flat surface, what you get is a two-dimensional version of a
>   map where longitude lines appear to be parallel. Such maps are often
>   used to show the entire surface of the globe all at once. An
>   MKMapPoint data structure represents a point on this two-dimensional
>   map.
>
> The actual units of a map point are tied to the underlying units used
>   to draw the contents of an MKMapView, but you should never need to
>   worry about these units directly. You use map points primarily to
>   simplify computations that would be complex to do using coordinate
>   values on a curved surface. By converting to map points, you can
>   perform those calculations on a flat surface, which is generally much
>   simpler, and then convert back as needed. You can map between
>   coordinate values and map points using the MKMapPointForCoordinate and
>   MKCoordinateForMapPoint functions.
>
> When saving map-related data to a file, you should always save
>   coordinate values (latitude and longitude) and not map points.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 4.0 and later. Declared In MKGeometry.h

Comment: So MKMapPoint/Rect x increases west, y increases south?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw something over a map that has a certain real-world size, for example, a scale, then in your calculations you would multiply any given length in meters with the result of `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(...)` to get the size in MKMapPoint units.

If your map displays only of small portion of the globe, `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(...)` will deliver roughly the same constant value for all the latitudes involved in your map. In this case, you can simply use the latitude in the middle of your map as the argument of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Also read in the documentation that a Mercator projection is used for the transformation. Here is an additional observation: northing (y) axis direction seems to be in reverse direction of standard mercator projections (positive direction is down instead of up).

Comment: this would have been better as a comment